# Question about mouse event

Tags: c#, events

I want to know the name of the event that occurs when Mose moves and clicks continuously ... 
Like the event which draw Lines in Paint ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `MouseMove` event, but you need to check arguments for pressed buttons:

```
void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         /* this is it */
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ... it works . I think that there is an event do that without any condition but I am failed in search about it . but this is a good idea .. thanks :)